# Azure Functions Re-executes SB Queue Message even though the maxAutoRenewDuration is set

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

We have an azure function written in typescript that runs for more than one minute for each SB Queue message. After it runs successfully, the same message is rerun.
Setting `autoComplete=true` in function.json and `"maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00"` in host.json do not seem to solve this.

host.json
[image]

function.json
[image]

Are we missing something here?

Comment: Is the lock lost for *every* message processed or just some messages?

Comment: can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

I have created an Azure function with a service queue trigger.

Thanks @Jdresc, for this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67726167/21525734) and refer This [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout).

As per below, the message lock duration should be 1, and then I have successfully sent and received the messages.

[image]

Azure Functions executes the service bus queue message when the maxAutoRenewDuration is set. I have tried the below code, and it executed successfully.

**function code:**

```
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.serviceBusQueue('serviceBusQueueTrigger111', {
    connection: 'servebusextend_SERVICEBUS',
    queueName: 'heyhello',
    handler: async (message, context) => {
        context.log('Service bus queue function processing message:', message);

     
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 180000)); 

        context.log('Message processing completed.');
    }
});
```

**host.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "concurrency": {
    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
    "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
  }
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "your storage connectionstring",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "servebusextend_SERVICEBUS": "servicebus connectionstring"
  },
  "Host": {
    "extensions": {
      "serviceBus": {
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]